# Print two-row string as one-row string Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a code that takes the value (text) from text widget and prints it. 
I noticed that, when I enter text in two rows (or more), it prints it in two rows (or more).

What code should I write so that it always prints the text in one row, no matter how much rows there are in text widget? Text should be separated by empty spaces on row brakes.

Code:

```
from tkinter import*

myApp=Tk()

t=Text(myApp, width=20, height=20)
t.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def printText():

    s = str(t.get('1.0', "end-1c"))    
    print(s)

but= Button(myApp, text="print", command=printText)
but.grid(row=0,column=1)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Comment: `print(s, end='')` ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace the line break character (`\n`) with a space.

```
def printText():
    s = t.get('1.0', "end-1c")
    print(s.replace('\n', ' '))
```

Comment: The `str()` is not needed here. Your `get()` method is converting to string already.

Answer (score 3):

I would split the string at the line break and then combine the words to a final string to print.

first we create a list of each row.
Then we combine each row to a single string.
Then we print the final result to the console.

Side note: I have updated your code to be more consistent with PEP8 and the preferred import method for tkinter.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

t = tk.Text(root, width=20, height=5)
t.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

def print_text():
    row_list = t.get('1.0', "end-1c").split("\n")
    final_string = ""

    for item in row_list:
        final_string = "{} {}".format(final_string, item)  

    print(final_string.strip())

but = tk.Button(root, text="print", command=print_text)
but.grid(row=0,column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Results:

[image]

Console:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I think that the second answer is easier, its much shorter. Your solution is great, and it works.